# How can I create an object that contains different parts, that can be accessed in edit mode?

Tags: modeling

How can I create one object and have different parts within that object and select them individually in edit mode?

A good example of what I mean is in the video linked below, where he has one gun object but can select different parts of it in edit mode.

Blender 2.90 Low Poly Weapon Rigging.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgLSHwex1dM

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: They probably have everything in separate mesh islands and are using L to select connected verts.

Comment: you can create several meshes within the same object, you can also join several objects with Ctrl J and they will be different meshes within the object

Comment: Thanks, moonboots answer was what i needed, thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create several meshes within the same object, you can also join several objects with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> and they will be different meshes within the same object. As explained by Allen Simpson, you can select a whole mesh in an object with <kbd>L</kbd>.